# Windows 10 missing after installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I had Windows 10. Then I installed Ubuntu alongside. Now I can't see the option to start Windows in the GRUB boot menu.

Note: the partitions still exist.

[image]

Comment: Your BIOS should have a setting letting you chose from which partition to boot. Can you boot from Windows using that?

Comment: i used automatic option to boot ubuntu so i didn't choose any partition i unlocated  space only

Comment: What's the output of `efibootmgr -v`?

Comment: the output efibootmgr: EFI variables are not supported on this system.
but i solved the problem thank you very much
just using sudo update-grub